# Storing and reading integers into a vector array from .txt file

Tags: c++, file, vector

My goal of the code is to create a vector array of integer values that are stored onto a text file and then retrieved from the text file to be stored back into the vector array and printed out to the screen.

So far, I have managed to store the values into a text file, but not retrieve them. 
The build messages state, "warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]".

If I attempt to run the code, the application crashes. If you are able to notify me of my mistake and explain why the crash occurred, much thanks.

IDE: Codeblocks

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen("sample.txt","w");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        cout << "[!] Cannot open file.";
        return(0);
    }
    vector<int> numArray;
    numArray.push_back(1);
    numArray.push_back(2);
    numArray.push_back(3);

    for(unsigned int x=0; x < numArray.size(); x++) {
        fprintf(fp, "%d ", numArray[x]);
    }

    numArray.clear();
    fclose(fp);

    FILE * fp2;
    fp2 = fopen("sample.txt","r");
    if(fp2 == NULL) {
        cout << "[!] Cannot open file.";
        return(0);
    }
    for(unsigned int x=0; !(feof(fp2)); x++) {
        fgets("%d", numArray[x], fp2);  //WARNING OCCURS HERE
    }

    fclose(fp);

    cout << "Vector: ";
    for(unsigned int x=0; x < numArray.size(); x++) {
        cout << numArray[x] << " ";
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't mix up C and C++. If you are programming in C++, use the features of `<iostream>` and `<string>` - don't use C streams and C=style null-terminated strings.

Comment: `fgets("%d", numArray[x], fp2);`  what? How the heck did this compile?

Comment: I'm unsure, but I think it came from the <stdlib.h> file. It was supposed to store the values from the file into 'x' index of the vector, but the vector contained no elements. Instead, I used numArray.push_back(x); to store the values "the correct way" using ifstream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use both `stdio` and `iostream`.
For files it'd be better if you used `fstream`, like this:

```
#include <fstream>

ifstream fin("sample.txt");

int number;

while(fin >> number)
{
    numArray.push_back(number);
}
```

Mixing C and C++ standard functions can lead to nasty things happening and is a bad practice.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback; I will definitely take your advice into consideration. My problem is now solved.

Comment: Why am I getting randomly downvoted on this post? Is something wrong with it?